# QML how force update / redraw

Tags: qt, qml

In my application I have a process which is started by clicking on a button.  The button already has a property to indicate when it is busy, this changes the colours to reflect the busy state.  When the process is finished the busy property is set back to false.

The problem is that although the steps are:

```
    button.busy = true
    ... Do something ...
    button.busy = false
```

In reality the button does not change to reflect the busy state until the process is almost complete, it then changes back to non-busy.

Is there anyway I can insert something after setting the busy state to true and before doing something to get the GUI to update and reflect the state?

My button QML:

```
Button {
    id: root
    property bool busy: false
    property bool showDropShadow: true
    property color bottomColour: MerlinStyle.greenButtonBottom
    property color iconColour: "white"
    property color topColour: MerlinStyle.greenButtonTop
    property string icon: ""
    opacity: (pressed || !enabled) ? 0.5 : 1.0

    onBusyChanged: {
    //Set the colours according to busy state
        if ( root.busy == true ) {
            root.bottomColour = MerlinStyle.indicatorOrange;
            root.topColour = MerlinStyle.indicatorOrange;
        } else {
            root.bottomColour = MerlinStyle.greenButtonBottom;
            root.topColour = MerlinStyle.greenButtonTop;
        }
    }
    background: Item {
        RadiusRectangle {
            id: rect
            anchors.fill: parent
            radius: MerlinStyle.rectRadius
            topLeftPointed: true

            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: root.topColour }
                GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: root.bottomColour }
            }
        }
        DropShadow {
            visible: showDropShadow && !pressed && enabled
            anchors.fill: rect
            horizontalOffset: 1
            verticalOffset: 2
            color: "#80000000"
            source: rect
        }
    }
    contentItem: Item {
        ColoredImage {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            height: parent.height * 0.85
            width: parent.width * 0.85
            source: icon
            color: root.iconColour
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to trigger an update using:

```
idOfButton.update
```

This always results in :

```
Button_QMLTYPE_28 : Update called for a item without content
```

The update function takes no parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call that function, it simply blocks the GUI thread, and those events which have been put to the event queue will wait until the program returns to the event loop again. That's why you cannot see that the button is updated based on the property changes.
This happens because of bad design. As per Qt documentation:

> - use asynchronous, event-driven programming wherever possible
> - use worker threads to do significant processing
> - never manually spin the event loop
> - never spend more than a couple of milliseconds per frame within blocking functions

You should not call a blocking function from within the GUI thread. You need to run that function from another thread or if you have a purpose to do that, you can call your function with a Timer which is a dirty hack.

```
Timer{
 id: dummyTimer
 interval:1
 repeat: false
 running: false
 onTriggered: {
   control.someLazyBlockingFunction();
   idOfButton.busy = false;
 }
}
Button{
 id: anotherButton
 ...
 onClicked:{
    idOfButton.busy = true;
    dummyTimer.running= true;
 }
}
```

Comment: The application itself is badly written but its beyond my control to change.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but might help someone.

In my case, my application is running on python (PyQt5 + QML), the event comes from QML code, and is handled in a slot (nothing new here).
The thing is, as stated in the qt documentation, you cannot block the main thread, so, the best way I found to handle it was spinning a new daemon thread to run the event code without hanging the frontend.

```
@pyqtslot(name="doMyButtonCallback")
def do_mybuttoncallback():
  def mybuttonwork():
    time.sleep(3)
    print("i did not hang your code!"
  t=threading.Thread(target=mybuttonwork)
  t.daemon=True
  t.start()
```